# Scala generic method. Accept any sequence of nummerical values

Tags: scala, types

Can I make a function in Scala accept both Vectors and Lists without specifying the concrete type value?

I've now got something like this:

```
def testFunc[V <: Seq[Int]](x: V) = x

testFunc(List(1, 3)) // res0: List[Int] = List(1, 3)
testFunc(Vector(1, 3)) // res1: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 3)
```

How can I modify this functions so it also accepts `Double` and `Int` values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can generalize the method a bit for any unary type constructor and avoid the type repetition (you can add a constraint for `F[_] <: Seq[_]` if you'd like):

```
def testFunc[F[_], A : Numeric](x: F[A]): F[A] = x
```

And then type inference works for us:

```
val resFirst = testFunc(Seq(1.0,2.0,3.0))
val resSecond = testFunc(List(1,2))
```

Comment: Ah.. So I need to specify the types when calling the function. Thanks I couldn't find in the docs.

Comment: @ritchie46 See my update, it makes the method invocation prettier.

Comment: Yes, that one is really elegant indeed!